# can i get data in b tag under the a tag with selenium with python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

can i get data in b tag under the a tag with selenium with python?

if i can, how? would you tell me solution?

this is structure of html

```
...
<div class = "cont_inner">
  <div class = "wrap_tit_ mg_tit">
    <a href = "href="https://cp.news.search.daum.net/p/97048679" class"f_link_b" onclick="smartLog(this, "dc=NNS&d=26DQnlvsWTMHk5CtBf&pg=6&r=2&p=4&rc=10&e1=163cv75CcAF31EvlGD&e3=0&ext=dsid=26DQnlvsWTMHk5CtBf", event, {"cpid": {"value": "163cv75CcAF31EvlGD"}});" target = "_blank"> == $0

        "하남지역자활센터,"
        <b>보건복지부</b>
        "간이평가 우수기관"
    </a>
</div>
```

and i wanna get data as like

```
"하남지역자활센터, 보건복지부 간이평가우수기관"
```

this is my code state

```
[['"하남지역자활센터, , 간이평가 우수기관"']]
```

and this is my source code for crawling data on the website

```
class crwaler_daum:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = []
        self.body = []
        self.url = input("please enter url for crawling data")
        self.page = input('please enter number of page to get data')
    
    def get_title(self):
        return self.title
    
    def set_title(self , title):
        self.title.append(title)
        
    def get_body(self):
        return self.body
    
    def set_body(self , body):
        self.body.append(body)
    
    def crwaling_title(self):
        title_list = []
        chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/바탕 화면/인턴/python/crwaler/news_crawling/chromedriver.exe')
        url = self.url
        response = requests.get(url , verify = False)
        root = lxml.html.fromstring(response.content)
        chrome_driver.get(url)
        
        for i in range(int(self.page) + 1):
            for j in root.xpath('//*[@id="clusterResultUL"]/li'):
                title_list.append((j.xpath('div[2]/div/div[1]/a/text()')))
                
        print(title_list)
            
            chrome_driver.get('https://search.daum.net/search?w=news&DA=PGD&enc=utf8&cluster=y&cluster_page=3&q=%EB%B3%B4%EA%B1%B4%EB%B3%B5%EC%A7%80%EB%B6%80&p={}'.format(i))
```

Comment: Where is the `<b>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

lxml has a built in function "[.text_content()](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods)" which "Returns the text content of the element, including the text content of its children, with no markup.". But after using this function, you should manipulate the string to acquire it like you want. I hope you will understand what I mean better with code below, but it may not be quite practical because I'm a beginner in Python too but it solves problem for now.

```
import lxml.html

html = '''
<div class = "cont_inner">
    <div class = "wrap_tit_ mg_tit">
        <a href = "href="https://cp.news.search.daum.net/p/97048679" class"f_link_b" onclick="smartLog(this, "dc=NNS&d=26DQnlvsWTMHk5CtBf&pg=6&r=2&p=4&rc=10&e1=163cv75CcAF31EvlGD&e3=0&ext=dsid=26DQnlvsWTMHk5CtBf", event, {"cpid": {"value": "163cv75CcAF31EvlGD"}});" target = "_blank">
            "하남지역자활센터,"
            <b>보건복지부</b>
            "간이평가 우수기관"
        </a>
</div>'''


my_html = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
a_element = my_html.xpath('//div[@class="wrap_tit_ mg_tit"]/a')
print(a_element[0].text_content())


def prettify_string(string):
    string = string.replace("\n", "").replace("\"", "").split(" ")
    while "" in string:
        string.remove("")
    string = " ".join(string)
    return string

"""
Prints:

            "하남지역자활센터,"
            보건복지부
            "간이평가 우수기관"
        
"""


print(prettify_string(str(a_element[0].text_content())))

"""
Prints:
하남지역자활센터, 보건복지부 간이평가 우수기관
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used lxml crawler yet, but you can use BeautifulSoup instead.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome('your direction')

chrome_driver.get('your url')

html = chrome_driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
b_tag = soup.find_all('b')
```

Comment: i'm not sure this is the result you wanted and sorry for not giving you the result about  lxml  package